# Apache Commons File Upload versus Ftp

Tags: java, apache, file-upload, ftp, apache-commons

Am trying to understand a Java based exsiting codebase involving file upload using [Apache File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) on the Apache server. Wondering if there is a reason why we cannot use or if there is any downside on using some `Ftp Client` to ftp the file versus having to rely on `Apache File Upload` Would highly appreciate if anyone can through more light on this.

Comment: File upload is for web application, where the user can upload the file through form submission on the web page. You will have to make each user of your web application to use Ftp Client to upload the file instead of the application itself.